# C++ Template Type Traits Issue

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I am new to making my own type traits and I want to make a type trait that allows me to identify if the passed type is the expected container.

```
template<typename T, typename ... Types>
struct is_array
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename ... Types>
struct is_array<std::array<Types...>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

I've adopted the format above and it works for all container types except for array:

```
constexpr bool state = is_array<std::array<int, 5>>::value;
```

The above evaluates to false when it should be true.  This only happens for the array class and I believe it is due to it having 2 template parameters that do not have default values.  I am unable to figure out a fix for this.

Comment: An actual specialization of `std::array` would never match `std::array<Types...>` since it has a non-type template parameter. You want something like `template<typename T, size_t N> struct is_array<std::array<T, N>> { ... };`

Comment: In your example `5` is not a type, so doesn't match `Types...`.

Comment: To add to the confusion, there is an `std::is_array` trait that specifically **not** detects `std::array` as an array.

Comment: so `is_std_array` would be a better name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your trait should have one, and only one template parameter: the expected array type:

```
template<typename T/*, typename ... Types*/>
struct is_array {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

Second, [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is defined as:

```
template<
    class T,
    std::size_t N
> struct array;
```

as first type parameter `T` and a non-type parameter `N` of type `std::size_t`.

Therefore, your *true* specialization should be:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_array<std::array<T,N>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Note, that instead of defining a member `value`, we prefer to inherit from [std::true_type and std::false_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) which provide some other member alias + conversion operator. The code then becomes:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_array : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_array<std::array<T,N>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: This is wonderful, works perfectly.  Thank you for showing me the proper way to do thisl.